# Is it possible to "focus stun" your pursuers?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

After watching a few multiplayer videos that have popped up on YouTube, I noticed that pursuers will get the focus ring around the stun indicator when you're close enough.

Do you get a bonus for landing a "focus stun?"  If so, is it a separate bonus apart from a "focus kill" (for the purposes of getting greater/extreme variety bonuses)?

Or was this just an oversight by the designers and focusing does nothing for you (just like focusing for a hidden gun kill in previous games)?

Comment: You don't really get any bonus for killing anyone unless the game specfically says "DO THIS".  Focus is mainly for the camera angle.

Comment: Ramhound, I think Jeff is talking about the ring around the kill indicator when staying in range of the target. If this ring is completely filled, you will receive a bonus upon a kill. Can't remember about Focus stun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely.  If you're able to keep your pursuer close within stun range until the focus ring fills up then stun, you will be awarded the stun *and* get a focus bonus.

However it doesn't count as a separate bonus between focus kills and focus stuns, a stun is a stun and there is no differentiation between the two.

Comment: Fortunately from what I've seen so far, there isn't so much "defensive smoke bomb (DSB) focus stuns" yet. I just hope it doesn't turn out to be as bad as OSBs.

Comment: Hmm, DSB focus stuns are a good new tactic. Thanks!